# how to display ~ backup files in gnome

Tags: linux, gnome

I'm using gnome. I created some text files. After I change something in `myfile.txt` there's `myfile.txt~` automatically created as a backup. Ok... now, on KDE I see these `~` files and I can delete them if I want but they're hidden in gnome... Gnome seems to treat them as special hidden files (just like `.mydir` directories) **How do I make `~` files visible in gnome** so I could edit or delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Nautilus file browser select *Show Hidden Files* from the *View* menu.

If you are asking this question because you really hate backup files and would rather not have them, most editors give you an option to not create them.  For example in gedit, select *Edit -> Preferences*.  On the *Editor* tab, there is a 'Create a backup copy of files before saving' checkbox.  If you uncheck that selection, then you won't create any ~ files.

Comment: *Show hidden files* is mapped to `<CTRL>-h` by default,